# AutoMapperMappingException Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I've found some strange behaviour regarding AutoMapper when I'm trying to map from this class

```
public class SkinAnalyzerResult {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswer> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> RecommendedProducts { get; set; }
}

public class SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswer {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Answer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SkinAnalyzerResult> Results { get; set; }
        public SkinAnalyzerQuestion Question { get; set; }
}
```

to this class

```
public class SkinAnalyzerResultDataModel {
        [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public ICollection<SkinAnalyzerResultQuestionAnswerDataModel> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SkinAnalyzerResultProductDataModel> RecommendedProducts { get; set; }
        public SkinAnalyzerDataModel SkinAnalyzer { get; set; }
}

public class SkinAnalyzerResultQuestionAnswerDataModel {
        public Guid ResultId { get; set; }
        public SkinAnalyzerResultDataModel Result { get; set; }
        public Guid QuestionAnswerId { get; set; }
        public SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswerDataModel QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswerDataModel {
        [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public String Answer { get; set; }
        public SkinAnalyzerQuestionDataModel Question { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SkinAnalyzerResultQuestionAnswerDataModel> Results { get; set; }
}
```

using this config map

```
cfg.CreateMap<SkinAnalyzerResultDataModel, SkinAnalyzerResult>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.SelectedAnswers,
                            opt => opt.MapFrom(
                                src => src.SelectedAnswers.Select(x => x.QuestionAnswer)
                            ))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.RecommendedProducts,
                            opt => opt.MapFrom(
                                src => src.RecommendedProducts.Select(x => x.Product)
                            ))
                        .ReverseMap();
```

When I tried to do that I got this AutoMapperMappingException
[image: AutoMapperMappingException]

as you can see I've specified to map SkinAnalyzerResult.Answers into SkinAnalyzerResultDataModel.SelectedAnswers.QuestionAnswer

is there something that I missed or do something wrong?

Comment: hello, already done that here is the config `cfg.CreateMap<SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswer, SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswerDataModel>().ReverseMap();`
    but still got the same exception

Comment: yes it's the same I've checked it many times

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cfg.CreateMap<SkinAnalyzerResultDataModel, SkinAnalyzerResult>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SelectedAnswers,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(
                            src => src.SelectedAnswers.Select(x => x.QuestionAnswer)
                        ))
```

The type of `SelectedAnswers` is `ICollection<SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswer>` while the type of `QuestionAnswer` is `SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswerDataModel`, so you also need to create mapping between the two models:

```
CreateMap<SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswerDataModel, SkinAnalyzerQuestionAnswer>()
                    .ForMember( //config if necessary)
```